# How to getTotalByteCount for FileDownloadTask for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get a totalSize of the file to be downloaded from the Firebase storage using Url in android app. The problem is that FileDownloadTask.getTotalByteCount()  returns -1. 
The documentation is not conclusive. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot.html#getTotalByteCount()

It talks about bytes to upload in Download Task. **I was wondering if anyone encountered this problem and any ways to resolve the issue?**

Here is the snippet

```
 for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String url = child.getValue().toString();
                    StorageReference filesRef = FirebaseStorage.
                            getInstance().
                            getReferenceFromUrl(url);
                    if (filesRef == null) continue;
                    final String fileName = filesRef.getName();
                    final String[] path = filesRef.getPath().split("/");
                    final String folder = path[path.length - 2];
                    File dir = new File(
                            context.
                                    getFilesDir().
                                    getPath() +
                                    File.separator + folder);
                    if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
                    final File localFile = new File(dir, fileName);
                    FileDownloadTask task = filesRef.getFile(localFile);
                    task.getSnapshot().getTotalByteCount();
                    Log.i("ccss", "totalByteCount :: " + 
                            task.getSnapshot().getTotalByteCount());
```

the output

```
I/ccss: totalByteCount :: -1
I/ccss: totalByteCount :: -1
I/ccss: totalByteCount :: -1
I/ccss: totalByteCount :: -1
```

I tried putting it inside onProgressListener and sometimes it returns -1 sometimes actual size. **Any explanations?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage file and its metadata are located on the Firebase servers.  Their values are loaded asynchronously and are not immediately available when you initiate the download with `filesRef.getFile(localFile)`.

The documentation for [FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot) does not define when the value of `getTotalByteCount()` becomes valid. Given that it must be fetched from the server, one can assume that it will **not** be valid when the download is initiated and may not be valid until the download completes sucessfully.

The code below samples the value of `getTotalByteCount()` at various points in the download.  It confirms your observation that `getTotalByteCount()` is -1 when the download is started and for the first few calls of `onProgress()`.  It then becomes valid on subsequent `onProgress()` calls and remains valid when `onComplete()` is called.

To reliably obtain the total byte count, use an `OnCompleteListener` or `OnSuccessListener` and obtain the count from the `FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot` returned in the callback.

```
FileDownloadTask task = filesRef.getFile(localFile);

FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot snap = task.getSnapshot();

Log.d(TAG, String.format("atStart: bytes=%d total=%d",
        snap.getBytesTransferred(), snap.getTotalByteCount()));

task.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot snap) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onProgress: bytes=%d total=%d",
                snap.getBytesTransferred(), snap.getTotalByteCount()));
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        long total = task.getResult().getTotalByteCount();
        long trans = task.getResult().getBytesTransferred();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onComplete: bytes=%d total=%d", trans, total));
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: SUCC");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: FAIL " + task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Example output:

```
atStart: bytes=0 total=-1
onProgress: bytes=0 total=-1
onProgress: bytes=0 total=-1
onProgress: bytes=262144 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=524288 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=786432 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=1048576 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=1310720 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=1572864 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=1835008 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=2097152 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=2359296 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=2621440 total=2814800
onProgress: bytes=2814800 total=2814800
onComplete: bytes=2814800 total=2814800
onComplete: SUCC
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that part is pretty clear. But there is no point in my situation to get a total byte count in onSuccessListener for 2 reasons. 1. Since the process is completed I can directly ask for length of the local file, 2. It needs to be done in onProgress for the progress bar to work properly. I guess I'll just have to do simple conditional and exclude -1 value.